# Is there non taxable investment account (like UK ISA) equivalent in Switzerland? How does one make tax-efficient Swiss investments?

Tags: taxes, investing, index-fund, switzerland

While we were living in the UK, we were using our extra money to invest in index funds via [ISA accounts](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts).

On these specific accounts, you do not pay Captial Gain Tax and they are excellent for long term investment. You are limited on how much you can invest that year (about 20k GBP) but they still really helped.

I am getting conflicting information about tax-efficient investing in Switzerland. [Here it says](https://www.englishforum.ch/finance-banking-taxation/13690-isa-equivalent.html) that you do not need ISAs because you are not being taxed anyway.

However simple google search says [there's 35% tax on the dividend.](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02-zsPVYj1O8R6QwoIa9YBv_VK9lA%3A1585300502640&ei=FsR9XsvcJpWpgAbA5L2QBQ&q=switzerland%20tax%20on%20dividend%20income&oq=switzerland%20tax%20on%20dividenincome&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgYIABAHEB4yBQgAEM0CMgUIABDNAjIFCAAQzQIyBQgAEM0CMgUIABDNAjoECAAQRzoGCAAQDRAeOggIABAIEA0QHlDaaFixcWDWfmgAcAN4AIABmwKIAb8KkgEFMC41LjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab) and that accumulation accounts that usually 'work' in some countries [are taxed anyway in Switzerland](https://thepoorswiss.com/distributing-vs-accumulating/)

**Are there any accounts, or other instruments, that would allow one to invest in index funds in a tax-efficient way in Switzerland?**